# Homomorphisms of matrix Lie groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-groups

Are there two matrix Lie groups $G$, $H$, i.e. closed subgroups of $\text{GL}(n,\mathbb{R})$ or $\text{GL}(n,\mathbb{C})$, and a smooth group homomorphism $f:G\rightarrow H$, such that $f(G)$ ist not a closed subgroup in $H$?

Comment: Comment on question v1: what is f?

Comment: What is v1, and what is $f$?

Comment: edited, sorry! :)